# Custom loss function Tensorflow / Keras penalizing relative distance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I built a tensorflow neural-network with three output classes.
My loss function is currently `val_mean_absolute_percentage_error` as not the absolute distance but the relative distance between target and predicted variable matters.
However, the mean absolute percentage error calculated as

```
1/n sum(|(y_test - y_pred) / y_test|)
```

is not fully appropriate for my problem as it penalizes stronger if `y_pred > y_test`

Example 1: `y_test = 5, y_pred = 2 --> Mape = 0.6`

Example 2: `y_pred = 5, y_test = 2 --> Mape = 1.5`

However, the above examples should penalize equally.

Does anyone know which (custom) loss function may more suitable for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

For bigger differences between the `y_true` and `y_pred` you could consider to use the `mse loss` instead of `mae loss`; in case of the RMSE/MSE, as the errors are squared prior to being averaged, the RMSE gives a higher weight for larger errors.

The problem is that you divide to `y_test`, hence the difference in results. You could first try to remove the denominator to obtain the same MAPE and if you still get bigger values in magnitude between `y_test` and `y_pred`, consider using `RMSE`.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I am looking for a metric which does not depend on the magnitude. The penalty for y_pred=50 and y_test=100 should be the same as for y_pred=2 and y_test=4. MSE/RMSE does not help here

Comment: I understand. Then I consider that removing the division to /y_test will solve your problem, because in that context only the absolute difference will be maintained :D, and thus in your example with y_true, y_pred |2-5| == |5-2|

Comment: You can try $\sum_i \frac{  |y_i - \hat{y}_i| }{  |y_i +\hat{y}_i| }$